# Custom listview background color change at runtime

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an application with a custom list view which has a textview and an imageview. When I click the image view, the background color should change. I tried to do this, but getting `NullPointerException` ...here is my code

**CustomListViewAdapter.java**

```
public class ViewHolder {
    TextView mName;
    ImageView mDeleteImage;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    holder = null;
    DataFields rowItems = (DataFields) getItem(position);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_field_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.mName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hmFieldName);
        holder.mDeleteImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.hmFieldDeleteImage);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

        holder.mDeleteImage.setTag(position);

        holder.mDeleteImage.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                count++;
                mListRowRL = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.hmFieldMainRL);
                mListRowRL.setBackgroundColor(color.list_row_bg); //throwing NullPointerException
            }
        });
    }

    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.mName.setText(rowItems.getName());

    return convertView;
}
```

Any kind of suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
holder.mDeleteImage.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                count++;
                mListRowRL = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.hmFieldMainRL);
                mListRowRL.setBackgroundColor(color.list_row_bg); //throwing NullPointerException
            }
        });
```

You are assigning a click listener to an ImageView which is fine.. But in your onClick method you are trying to search the View passed in (Which is an ImageView) for your row.. ImageViews will not contain any child views so your mListRowRL will always be null.
Try something like this

```
final View clickView = convertView;
holder.mDeleteImage.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(final View view) {
                    count++;
                    clickView.setBackgroundColor(color.list_row_bg); 
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this weird bug one time

I solved it (well Google it :)) with this, on your XML :

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
```

Then you mus tassign a selector to your root row item :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutApplication"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/list_selector">
```

Finally the selector (list_selector.xml on res/color) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/light_blue"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/light_blue"
        android:state_selected="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
</selector>
```